# Drupal problem, how to create a fast content module?

Tags: drupal

Hi I need to create a module in drupal to display some data, not being a drupal developer and after reading a couple of tutorials, i cant seem to display anything.

I have the next code:

```
<?php
function helloworld_perm() {
  return array('access helloworld content');
} 

function helloworld_listado(){
 return "yea";
}

function helloworld_menu(){
    $items = array();
    $items["listado"] = array(
        'title' => t('Listado de empresas'),
        'callback' => 'helloworld_listado',
        'access' => array('access helloworld content'),
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM 
      );
    return $items;
}
```

When i enter /listado i get a Access denied
You are not authorized to access this page.

Any idea what im doing wrong?
If i go to the admin->module->permissions, i have checked the permision for all roles to access hellowold content.

Ty!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the way that your menu array is structured in `helloworld_menu()`, I'm assuming that this is Drupal 6. If so, you need to rename 'access' to 'access arguments'. See http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_menu/6.

The Drupal API documentation also includes a heavily-commented page_example.module that's doing basically what you're doing here, which you might want to check out: http://api.drupal.org/api/file/developer/examples/page_example.module/6/source

Hope that helps!

Oh. And don't forget to clear your cache afterwards from the "Clear cache" button on Administer >> Site configuration >> Performance.

Answer (score 1):

```
 => t('Listado de empresas'),
    'page callback'    => 'helloworld_listado',
    'access arguments' => array('access helloworld content'),
    'type'             => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );
return $items;
}
```

Note that , `MENU_NORMAL_ITEM` being the default value for `type`, you do not need to specify it.

Also, as our esteemed webchick just said

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using a mix of Drupal 5 (array contents) and Drupal 6 (no $may_cache, $items indexed by path) syntaxes for hook_menu.

If you are using Drupal 6, this should look like:

```
<?php
function helloworld_perm() {
  return array('access helloworld content');
} 

function helloworld_listado(){
 return "yea";
}

function helloworld_menu(){
    $items = array();
    $items["listado"] = array(
        'title'            => t('Listado de empresas'),
        'page callback'    => 'helloworld_listado',
        'access arguments' => array('access helloworld content'),
        'type'             => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
      );
    return $items;
}
?>
```

Note that, `MENU_NORMAL_ITEM` being the default value for 'type', you do not need to specify it.

Also, as our esteemed webchick just said, you can find a detailed explanation on the page she points to.

Answer (score 0):

just FYI , above link moved to

http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/page_example--page_example.module/6